# Why std::pair<string, int> doesn't compare with std::string?

Tags: c++, comparison, c++14, std-pair

Why I can't compile the code bellow?

```
string m = "MEOW";
pair <string, int> p = { "M", 0 };
if (m[0] == p.first)
   p.second += 10;
```

I get the error:

```
main.cpp:18:14: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'std::__1::basic_string<char>')
    if (m[0] == p.first)
        ~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Perhaps you want a `std::pair<char, int>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to compare `m[0]` as a new string object and it works:

```
string m = "MEOW";
pair <string, int> p = { "M", 0 };
if (string(1, m[0]) == p.first)
   p.second += 10;
```

Comment: This is very different from what you initially posted. Here you are *creating* a new string from a char, then comparing two string objects.

Comment: @JesperJuhl yes, I understand. Most likely I incorrectly formulated the question.

Answer (score 2):

`p.first` is a `string`. `m[0]` is a `char`. You cannot compare those two types.

Comment: Even if I explicitly specify `(char)p.first`?

Comment: @Jeffy how would casting a `string` to a `char` ever make any sense? A string is *not* a char. A cast is not magic. It can only convert sensibly between types that are convertible to eachother. If not, you just get garbage (Undefined Behaviour).